Is a user (not current user) part of a user group on the local pc?
Current windows user can run application feature1-10.
Another user can run application feature 1-20.
if the current user needs to run feature 11-20 they ask another user to temporarily run the required feature.
Pop up a login screen retrieving different username and password (I can do that I think), validate credentials with windows, check the new user is part of windows group 'Feature 11-20' and allow them to run the feature.
This works for current user
using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    bool a = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    bool b = principal.IsInRole(domain + "\\DCO Administrator");
}

Can't seem to find equivalent for a different user.
